Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, copyfile | errno: -4048 | Nextjs 14.2.4
I'm trying to generate the static production version using fake api routes with data from a local json
and the following error appears:
PS D:\programas\fakeapi> yarn build
yarn run v1.22.19
$ next build
  ▲ Next.js 14.2.4
  - Environments: .env.local

   Creating an optimized production build ...
 ✓ Compiled successfully
 ✓ Linting and checking validity of types
 ✓ Collecting page data
 ✓ Generating static pages (7/7)
 ✓ Collecting build traces

> Build error occurred
[Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, copyfile 'D:\programas\fakeapi\.next\server\app\api.body' -> 'D:\programas\fakeapi\out\api'] {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'copyfile',
  path: 'D:\\programas\\fakeapi\\.next\\server\\app\\api.body',
  dest: 'D:\\programas\\fakeapi\\out\\api'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
PS D:\programas\fakeapi> ^C
PS D:\programas\fakeapi>

I've already tried, deleting the second parameter where the response status is, I've tried to simplify, I've even tried to use json directly in the response, all the options give the same error, but I've tried to delete all the routes and create a VERY simple api route with just api/route.ts and it works, so I can say that it can be created, but I don't know why you're having this problem.
The repo is public, I appreciate everyone's help--
https://github.com/gabriel-logan/fakeapi
